# Difference between && and || operator in Bash

Tags: bash

This is confusing me.

```
false || echo "Oops, fail" # Oops, fail
true || echo "Will not be printed" #
true && echo "Things went well" # Things went well
false && echo "Will not be printed" #
```

true return 0 exit code and false returns 1.  I am unable to understand how || and && are working. Do both of them work on exit codes or the actual output of the command? What is the difference between && and ||  operator here?

The above code snippet is from [the missing semester of your CS education lecture 2](https://missing.csail.mit.edu/2020/shell-tools/).

Comment: Yes, they both work on exit codes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x && y` executes `x`, then only executes `y` if `x` **succeeds** (i.e., has an exit status of 0)

`x || y` executes `x`, then only executes `y` if `x` **fails** (i.e., has a non-zero exit status)

The output of `x` is irrelevant.

One place they do *not* differ is in precedence. Unlike Boolean operators in other languages, `&&` and `||` have equal precedence, so something like

```
a || b && c
```

is parsed and evaluated the same as

```
{ a || b; } && c
```

rather than

```
a || { b && c; }
```